Specify geo location of web pages (each is different)
I have a web app that lists events, sort-of like meetup.com. Every event has a location. And each event has its own web page describing that event.
Is there a way to specify the geocoded and/or address location of the event in the meta data of the web page for that event?
My goal is that Google then knows the individual searching is in Denver and so will show them matching searches for event pages in the Denver area, but not show them events in the Chicago area.

If you want to ensure Google accurately recognizes the location of each event on your website, using structured data like schema.org's Event schema is a great approach. By embedding this data in your page’s metadata, you provide Google with precise details like the event's address and coordinates, which helps in targeting users searching in the relevant geographic area.
For example, you can specify the event’s location with structured data in JSON-LD format. This might include the venue name, street address, city, and even geographic coordinates (latitude and longitude). Here’s how you might implement it:
      <script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Event",
  "name": "Tech Meetup in Denver",
  "startDate": "2024-09-15T19:00-07:00",
  "endDate": "2024-09-15T22:00-07:00",
  "location": {
    "@type": "Place",
    "name": "Downtown Conference Center",
    "address": {
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      "streetAddress": "123 Main St",
      "addressLocality": "Denver",
      "postalCode": "80202",
      "addressRegion": "CO",
      "addressCountry": "US"
    },
    "geo": {
      "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
      "latitude": 39.7392,
      "longitude": -104.9903
    }
  },
  "description": "Join us for a tech meetup in downtown Denver."
}
</script>

By implementing this, you make it easier for Google to associate your event pages with specific locations. This means that when someone in Denver searches for events, your Denver-based event is more likely to show up, while events from other locations, like Chicago, are less likely to be displayed to those users. Additionally, this also makes your events eligible for rich snippets in search results, giving them more visibility.

My hunch is that Google is probably smart enough to read the page and extract location information from it without any extra help. It should be able to determine the targeted location and adjust search results accordingly.
However, if you'd like to add metadata that spells it out explicitly for Google, and to be eligible for Event rich snippets, consider adding Event Schema.
Here's an abbreviated example pulled from the Google documentation I linked above:
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Event",
  "name": "The Adventures of Kira and Morrison",
  "startDate": "2025-07-21T19:00-05:00",
  "endDate": "2025-07-21T23:00-05:00",
  "location": {
    "@type": "Place",
    "name": "Snickerpark Stadium",
    "address": {
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      "streetAddress": "100 West Snickerpark Dr",
      "addressLocality": "Snickertown",
      "postalCode": "19019",
      "addressRegion": "PA",
      "addressCountry": "US"
    }
  },
  "description": "The Adventures of Kira and Morrison is coming to Snickertown in a can't miss performance."
}
</script>


This is great - thank you. Any idea what the application/ld+json represents?

It represents JSON-LD, a structured data format based on the JSON data format. It's the most popular and straightforward way to include structured data (metadata about "things") on web pages (like events, job postings, local business details, reviews, rentals, etc.) Check Google's structured data markup page to see details about all the types of structured data Google's crawler is designed to read.

Thank you again for that link. Setting the full event metadata, and for the organizations the org metadata, is a big win. Contributors like you make this site great.
